# Java Slick2D get panel x and y

Tags: java, slick2d

i need to get the current Xpos and Ypos of the game panel to make make a screen shot of it,i'm using Slick2D libraries, i know how to get the Width and the Height but stucked on getting the Xpos and the Ypos.
here how is how i've implemented the render methode :

```
public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException {

    BufferedImage image = null;
    try {
        image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(0,0,gc.getWidth(),gc.getHeight()));
    } 
    catch (HeadlessException e1) { e1.printStackTrace(); } 
    catch (AWTException e1) {   e1.printStackTrace(); }
    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("res/screenshot.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    Image SS=new Image("res/screenshot.png");
    g.drawImage(SS, 0, 0);
    g.drawString("Game Paused !", 100, 100);

}
```

i need to get the Xpos and Ypos to put them in the rectangle constructor

Comment: When you have a question about code, show some code.

Comment: Thanks, this  is much better. I am looking at the javadoc for Slick right now trying to find how to retrieve an x/y position.